# What are extra stars used for?

Tags: kingdom-rush

In Kingdom Rush, it only takes 65 stars to buy all upgrades.  What good are the stars once you have upgraded everything?  This is on the android version if there are version differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really for completeness after all the upgrades and to track your progress to complete the game/pass all levels